# Windows 10 always download something

Tags: windows-10

I am using windows 10 enterprise version. The problem is that it is always downloading something in background. Don't know what is it. It is not even windows update but it downloading and using full bandwidth. What is the reason of it and how can I stop it ?[image]

Comment: Windows 10 no longer makes you approve each update before it's installed, security updates are simply installed, even if your using Windows 10 Enterprise.  You can control which updates are installed by using WSUS.  You only get the ability to defer feature updates ( i.e. 1511,1607,1703) and in 1703 you will gain the ability to pause quality updates (security improvements) for 30 days.

Comment: So I guess I am wondering.  What behavior exactly do you want to prevent?  If you want more control, change your configuration from "available updates will be downloaded and installed automatically" to one of the options that provide more control (although you still won't get the old ui where you pick and choose).

Comment: @Ramhound as I said. When I am seeing that my full bandwidth is consumed but my windows is not updating. I just wanted to find the reason which process is continuously downloading something  .  And it turned out it  is svchost.exe . If I kill all those process it starts automatically. I want to stop it permanently .

Comment: If you use that method.  Windows won't update at all.  You can schedule updates to install on Windows 10 Enterprise.  Additionally you can use WSUS and then you will have total control over when updates are installed.  You can configure your other machines to use other devices on the network to download updates also.

Comment: ***Check the store settings and stop Automatic Updates, I think that's your problem.
Peace.....***

Answer (score 1):

Look for any Background services that is running.

Use the Task Manager (Right Click on Task Bar at the bottom of the screen, then click on Task Manager), Go on "Network" Tab, and see what is taking all that Bandwidth. on the Task Manager Network tab, click "Resource Monitor", which shows the individual connections and program that owns each. (Thanks to @Ben_Voigt)

It's normal to have a constant use of the bandwidth, but it shouldn't overload it.

Comment: Keep going... on the Task Manager Network tab, click "Resource Monitor", which shows the individual connections and program that owns each.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm using Windows in French, so it's kind of hard to translate every steps. But yes indeed, I'll edit my post and add this.

Comment: @Darksoulpk68 Thanks , I have found the process which is consuming all my bandwidth . it is svchost.exe . What can I do now ?

Comment: @MithunSarkerShuvro: You will have more than one instance of `svchost.exe` running, so take note of the Process ID (PID).  Then in Task Manager's "Services" tab, you can find which service (or services) run in that instance of svchost.  If more that one, you can stop some of them until you find which service is responsible for the network traffic.

Comment: Do no forget to set the Question as Answered if your problem is solved. You can also create your own answer if something else fixed it.